(Updated) Seeking proof to Dynamical Systems past exam question
I have searched and found one proof for the below which I have not been able to completely process and AI has been unable to provide sufficient reasoning. I hope you may be able to assist.
We have that $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism, and that $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is a fixed point of a hyperbolic saddle type.
We know that all points do not remain in an open ball $B$ centered at p after one iteration.
We wish to prove that given any positive integer $k$, there exists an open neighbourhood $V$ of $p$ such that every periodic point contained in $V\backslash\{p\}$ has prime period greater than $k$.
I have seen the question asked here, but as mentioned above, could not make complete sense of the provided proof: Periodic point near Hyperbolic fixed point
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Based on a different version of the proof below, it seems as if the equation $f^k(x) - x$ can indeed be factored into $[f(x) - x]G(x)$, where $G(x)$ is a polynomial whose real roots are the periodic points of the k-cycle. If this is true, then no periodic point for a given k can be part of a smaller k-cycle. Would that be a correct way to understand the problem?

What part of that proof you don't understand?

@Gonçalo There are a few things : 1 - why we are taking a subsequence that approaches p if the points are on a k-cycle. I don't get how they could be on the k-cycle and simultaneously approach p. 2: If we are looking at points that approach p which are each part of a smaller k-cycle as we get closer to p in V are we saying that F^k(x)-x=[F(x)-x]G(x) where the real roots of G(x) are the elements of the k-cycle and so cant have period less than k unless k=2?

Did you add "saddle point" on your own or was this given in the task? The link does not have it. In the context of fixed points, "hyperbolic" may also just simply mean that the eigenvalues of the Jacobian at the fixed point have real parts bounded well away from zero. This has more to do with how well the linearized system is similar to the non-linear system. But it makes no claim on the dimension of the stable and unstable submanifolds.

What is a "prime period", a period that is a prime number or the primitive or smallest non-zero period? Can you say something about that statement when $f$ is linear?

I meant two comments up "eigenvalues well away from the unit circle", the other condition was for ODE.

@LutzLehmann - thank you for your points:
*saddle point was given in my version of the task .
*prime period - being the min number of cycles to get back to the original point in the orbit.
*it doesnt provide an actual map for f but I guess since the point is hyperbolic that the linearisation will be accurate for fixed point classification.

A different argument is the following:
$p$ is a hyperbolic fixed point of $f^m$ for each $m\in\mathbb N$. Let $V_m$ be an open neighborhood of $p$ without further fixed points of $f^m$ (apply say the Grobman-Hartman theorem). Then $V=\bigcap_{n\le m}V_m$ is an open neighborhood of $p$ and $V\setminus\{p\}$ has no fixed points of $f^n$ for any $n\le m$.
